# Apache mod_rewrite rewrite if URI doesn't match

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Hello I have problem with RewriteCond with RewriteRule not working as expected.

If I have

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/fr/?.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/en/$1 [R=302,L]
```

When I access http://example.com/fr/test it correctly rewrites to http://example.com/en/fr/test

However when I negate the condition

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/fr/?.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/en/$1 [R=302,L]
```

When I access http://example.com/fr/test I get redirected to http://example.com/en/index.php while I would expect no redirection.

When I remove this rule and condition, no redirection happens.

Comment: It's strange. The rule with negated condition looks OK and should work. Did you restart your server?

Comment: @starkeen It is done in .htaccess. If it would need restart, no redirection changes would be seen between changes to rules.